# Use same jquery function for different html li objects

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create a function which copies text from a specific list element into an input form. What I'm struggling with is that my function just copies all the text instead of the specific element. Does somebody have any advice how to indicate the list objects correctly (and dynamically)? Thx!

```
<!--Copy into Form Field-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!--Input field and list items-->
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Input" size="200">

<li class="test" id="li1">test</li>
<li class="test" id="li2">brumbo</li>

  <!--Function to Copy list items into input field-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.test').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#input2');

        text.val(text.val() +','+ $('.test').text());    
    });
});
</script>
```

Output after clicking on e.g. test should be: ,test (instead of ,testbrumbo)

Comment: Hi Feivel!
I will recomend you to investigate about the use of 'this' as a selector in jquery. Here is an useful link: http://html-tuts.com/jquery-this-selector/. The use of 'this' selector would help you a lot in the use of jquery. And only as an advice... i will recomend you to try learning Vue, it's an amazing framework and the jump from jquery to vue will be somoth to you. Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change `$('.test').text()` to `$(this).text()` for get current li as

```js
$(function () {
    $('.test').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#input2');

        text.val(text.val() +','+ $(this).text());    
    });
});
```

```html
<!--Copy into Form Field-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!--Input field and list items-->
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Input" size="200">

<li class="test" id="li1">test</li>
<li class="test" id="li2">brumbo</li>

  <!--Function to Copy list items into input field-->
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` returns the combined text content of *all* elements in your collection, and `$('.test')` has selected *all* elements with that class in your document.

You want `$(this).text()`, to only get the text of the current element that you are currently handling the `click` event for.